Extract Data from a SharePoint list Lookup Column with Data Factory
I'm train to extract Data from a SharePoint list Lookup Column with a copy data in datafactory but it returns the id of the referenced table, instead of the value I need. How could I solve this problem?
How looks:enter image description here
How it should look: enter image description here
I tried to see from sharepoint if I could do something and I couldn't.
I try to ensure that the column can arrive with the data I need without having to make transformations along the way.

Can you show how you are creating column? Is it the file column or list column? provide pipeline configurations?
